# How to choose which iPhone model simulator to run my react native app?

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native app, and I do testing on iOS Simulator.

However, it always runs on iPhone 6, and i don't know how I can switch to other iPhone models like iPhone 6 Plus or 5.

I can start a different device manually by going to Simulator -> Hardware -> Device -> iOS -> iPhone 6 Plus.

But the app is installed only on iPhone 6, and it always starts iPhone 6 when I run `react-native run ios`.

How can I change it so that I can run the app on different iOS Simulator devices?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s Plus"`

As far as I can tell there is currently no way to specify the OS.

Comment: To list available simulators do: `xcrun simctl list devices`

Comment: Don't forget to quit the current simulator, otherwise the new one won't show up.

Comment: It worked for me without quitting the current simulator

Answer (score 0):

you could open your project in Xcode on mac  and choose build target, then build.