# Specify device type when simulation

Tags: react-native

I really like that I can run "react-native run-ios" from terminal without opening Xcode. Is it somehow possible to specify which iOS device to simulate?

If I manually change the device in Simulator->Hardware->Device, the simulator exits the react native app.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37155125/1783214